# Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, declaration, tk-toolkit

i have some problematic python code..

```
import mysql.connector
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import sys
    sys.path.insert(0,"/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages")
import pymysql

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='rattekop',

password='password',
host='localhost',
database='buyers')
### db = client.rptutorials
### db


class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Building the Car")
        self.name = "Lamborghini"
        self.max_speed = "220 mph"
    
def display(self):
    print(f"Name: {self.name}")
    print(f"Max Speed: {self.max_speed}")
    
 #creating object of the class
    myCar = Car()

 print("-----------------")

 #calling the display function of the myCar object
 myCar.display()

 ### cnx.close()



 # declare the window
 window = Tk()
 # set window title
 window.title("Python GUI App")
 # set window width and height
 window.configure(width=500, height=300)
 # set window background color
 window.configure(bg='lightgray')

 window.mainloop()


 window__str__one= tk.Tk()
 window__str__one = Text("root", height=10)
 window_str_one.pack()`
```

the error is as in subject/title of this question.. for some reason the                    window__str__one=tk.Tk() variable has/gets no reference to the declaration at the top.. i have no knowledge of python referencing.. (or anything else, joke :P)

if you know what to do please do not hesitate to answer..

--for some reason the "import" code part is not contained in the whole code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Seems something is missing:

import tkinter as tk

Hope it helps.

Comment: its there but6 you can't/couldnt see because of some formatting issues